# SKTileMap Not Displaying Any Tiles

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground, tile

I'm creating this simple platformer game using SpriteKit in Swift Playgrounds as a small project.

However, when I created the SKTileSet, the TileMap, etc. and ran the playground, none of the tiles actually showed up.

The other SKSpriteNodes, which I've created also in the same SpriteKit Scene File, displays perfectly.

The code:

`GameScene.swift`

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    var worldLayer: Layer!
    var backgroundLayer: RepeatingLayer!
    var mapNode: SKNode!
    var tileMap: SKTileMapNode!

    var lastTime: TimeInterval = 0
    var dt: TimeInterval = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        createLayers()
    }

    func createLayers() {
        worldLayer = Layer()
        worldLayer.zPosition = 2
        addChild(worldLayer)
        worldLayer.layerVelocity = CGPoint(x: -200.0, y: 0.0)

        backgroundLayer = RepeatingLayer()
        backgroundLayer.zPosition = 0
        addChild(backgroundLayer)

        for i in 0...1 {
            let backgroundImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
            backgroundImage.name = String(i)
            backgroundImage.scale(to: frame.size, width: false, multiplier: 1.0)
            backgroundImage.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
            backgroundImage.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0 + CGFloat(i) * backgroundImage.size.width, y: 0.0)
            backgroundLayer.addChild(backgroundImage)
        }

        backgroundLayer.layerVelocity = CGPoint(x: -100.0, y: 0.0)

        load(level: "Level_0-1")
    }

    func load(level: String) {
        if let levelNode = SKNode.unarchiveFromFile(file: level) {
            mapNode = levelNode
            worldLayer.addChild(mapNode)
            loadTileMap()
        }
    }

    func loadTileMap() {
        if let groundTiles = mapNode.childNode(withName: "GroundNode") as? SKTileMapNode {
            tileMap = groundTiles
            tileMap.scale(to: frame.size, width: false, multiplier: 1.0) 
            PhysicsHelper.addPhysicsBody(to: tileMap, and: "ground")
            for child in groundTiles.children {
                if let sprite = child as? SKSpriteNode, sprite.name != nil {
                    ObjectHelper.handleChild(sprite: sprite, with: sprite.name!)
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

How may I fix this issue?

Is it related to the fact that I am using Swift Playgrounds instead of it being a project?

I have confirmed that there are no spelling errors and that it all runs i.e. there are actually the tiles as nodes in the background, but none of it shows up.

What I mean is that with the tiles deleted, the screen will only contain 31 nodes.

But when I added the TileMap and the tiles, the screen will then contain 162 nodes, but the tiles just don't show up.

Thanks for the help, I am really struggling with this.

Comment: helps if you post some code, a million things could be wrong

Comment: Sure. The PhysicsHelper and the ObjectHelper just adds physics to the nodes in the TileMap.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar troubles playground and tilemap seems to have a conflict
Put your code in xcode project and see if it works

Comment: Wow, it works! It seems that the issue is that the playground doesn't recognize the TileSet as I found out it returns `nil` when I added a print statement for the name of the TileSet.

Comment: So, how to fix this problem in the future? Is this a bug? I've already recreated my game in an Xcode project and it works fine.